# What can't the U.S. do vis-a-vis Taiwan due to having an unofficial relations with Taiwan?

Tags: united-states, china

> To this day, the U.S. “one China” position stands: the United States
> recognizes the PRC as the sole legal government of China but only
> acknowledges the Chinese position that Taiwan is part of China. **Thus,
> the United States maintains formal relations with the PRC and has
> unofficial relations with Taiwan.** The “one China” policy has
> subsequently been reaffirmed by every new incoming U.S.
> administration. The existence of this understanding has enabled the
> preservation of stability in the Taiwan Strait, allowing both Taiwan
> and mainland China to pursue their extraordinary political and
> socioeconomic transitions in relative peace.

https://www.csis.org/analysis/what-us-one-china-policy-and-why-does-it-matter

I was reading this and was wondering what were the difference between an formal and an unofficial relation with a country. Due to their unofficial relation, is there anything the U.S. cannot do vis-a-vis Taiwan without breaking their own one-China policy?